# What is elasticsearch supported Logstash-output-jdbc plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

My use case is to transfer data from Elasticsearch to Postgres. While exploring, I could find logstash-ouput-jdbc plugin(https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc?tab=readme-ov-file) but it does not seem to be officially supported and there can be vulnerabilities and risks. Can someone please point to the official link in the Elasticsearch guide where i can find this plugin.
Also, I am not sure how logstash-plugin list --group output provides me logstash-ouput-jdbc as one of the plugins if it is not supported officially.
[image]
Thanks in advance